# Where is "Edit Active Target" in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I was following [setup instructions](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions) to add ASIHTTPRequest to my project
and it asks me to "Edit Active Target". Now that I'm using Xcode 4, I don't see that menu item anywhere. Where can I edit my active target?

[image: Edit Active Target in Xcode 3]

Answer (score 6):

There's no set active target in XCode 4.

Instead you can select it at left top of the screen at the right of "stop" button.
You can select any target(with devices) you set in the drop down list.

Answer (score 2):

XCode has changed a bit - the step you mention requires you to link your app against some frameworks. To do that in XCode 4,

Project (Apple-1) > Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries

That last pane has a + button that will bring up a dialog box almost identical to the one in your link.

Comment: I don't have ( or find) "project" in my xcode , can you please post a picture ? thnk you

Comment: Wonderful news! Mark the question as answered.

Comment: @siMonAkro, could you please tell where you found it ? I have the same ASIHttpRequest setup problem :)

Comment: gaa, I hate "found it" comments that don't explaining *where*. Luc, see my answer if you're still searching for this dialog – I finally found it.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else (like me) was looking where the old 'Edit Active Target' menu went, or where the 'Project' option is that Rythmic Fistman mentions in his answer, here's how to find it:

In the toolbar:
View -> Navigators -> Project

Then double-click on your project.

You then get a window where you can change all the settings, just like with 'Edit Active Target' in XCode3.