# How to Set Active Target in XCode 4.5+

Tags: preprocessor, xcode4.5

I have an iOS Application that I am managing that has two targets.

This was done as both targets utilize 90% of the same code.
Each target has a specific Preprocessor Macro assigned to so blocks of code can be distinguished for each Target.

Everything compiles correct for both targets.

The problem though is that the xcode only auto compeletes and syntax highlights for the first taget.

For Example:
Target => "MainTarget"  -  Preprocessor Macro => TARGET_A=1 
Target => "OtherTarget" - Preprocessor Macro => TARGET_B=1

Then if I have the following code:

```
#if TARGET_B
    NSLog(@"Log Something %f", 3.5);
#else
    NSLog(@"Log other stuff %i", 4);
#endif
```

Only NSlog(@"Log other stuff %i", 4);  is correctly colored.

Compiling and Running works fine, but I'd like to visually know before building and launching that I have a typo.

As such it would be nice to be able to switch weither MainTarget or OtherTarget is the active code for the editor.

Comment: I have managed to find a work around.  1) Set the Target to the target that you want the preprocessor Marcro's to evaluate true for.  2) Build the project.  3) Exit XCode and Restart XCode.  Xcode now auto completes and syntax highlights for that Target.    It would still be nice to switch targets without restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that XCode no longer has that feature. Try changing the scheme next to the Stop button.

Source: [Where is "Edit Active Target" in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048534/where-is-the-edit-active-target-in-xcode-4)